# "Define" is undefined in my lisp compiler (Steel Bank Common Lisp)

Tags: lisp, scheme, common-lisp

I am studying the book on SICP (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs) which require me to learn lisp so i installed a lisp compiler called SBCL (Steel Bank Common Lisp) for windows. The thing is i came across this code from the book:

```
(define pi 3.14159)
(define radius 10)
(* pi (* radius radius))
```

Saved it on notepad++ as filename.lisp and run it.

An Error occurred which says:
"The function COMMON-LISP-USER::DEFINE is undefined." 
Why is this so? How do i make this work?

Comment: DrRacket is a great IDE/SCheme implementation and someone has made support for SICP: http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SICP is a book about a programming language called "Scheme". It says so in the foreword of the book. In fact, here's the website of the book: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/

SBCL is an implementation of a programming language called "Common Lisp". `define` is not a predefined function (or other form) in Common Lisp.

The solution is either for you to learn Common Lisp from a book about that, or to get an implementation of Scheme.

Comment: Thanks for verifying. Now i have the right tools in learning this book.